# Looking for a multiline text gadget for Intuition on a 1.3 Amiga

Tags: amiga, programming, amiga-500, gui

I've come to understand that Intuition, the GUI framework on the stock A500 has 4 types of gadgets:

1. 'boolean' - checkboxes and buttons
2. 'Proportional' - sliders
3. string inputs
4. integer inputs

I'm looking for a multi line string *output* so that i can render a paper tape from a calculator app I'm building.

Failing that, is there a 3rd party library that enriches the available set of gadgets?

Comment: Couldn't you use the base Gadget "class", which is able to render a linked list of text "objects" relative to the top left of the containing Gadget?

Comment: @BrianH, that should probably be an answer, not a comment

Comment: There’s no built-in and the 1.3 gadgets were not extensible in the way, AOS2.0 introduced. You can use the `console.device`, which supports being limited to a rectangular region of a window, so it would cooperate with other gadgets (but only one console per window, afaik).

Answer (score 8):

I used Intuisup by Torsten Jurgeleit for my application when running under WB1.3 to provide the same functionality as was available with gadtools in WB2.x

I think V4.5 is the version I used and a quick search shows that it can be found on Fish Disk 562 described as

> A shared library with support routines for using texts, menus, borders, gadgets, requesters, and more, under AmigaDOS 1.3. Includes a template editor and source to library and test programs. This is version 4.5, an update to version 4.4 on disk 715. Author: Torsten Jurgeleit

My application ran under 1.3 and 2.x so I wrote a layer that provided the controls and switched between libraries at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The intuition.library also provides the "PrintIText" function, which can be used to print text using the RastPort of your window.

This is not a gadget and does not provide any functionality like scroll bars, so you will need to add your own proportional gadgets if you need them.

More information on PrintItext can be found [online](http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Includes_and_Autodocs_3._guide/node03D9.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you only need a text output window you can open a pseudo terminal with parameters for the horizontal and vertical window offsets, the window width, height and title text. with C, you can do

```
FILE* fp = fopen("CON:30/30/510/175/theWindow", "w");
```

to open a window at screen offset 30,30 that is 510 by 175 pixels and has the title "theWindow".

After this you can use fprintf to write text to the window.